# The builds tools v143 not found

Tags: c#

I am trying to build a project and I get this error:

error MSB8020: The build tools for v143 (Platform Toolset = 'v143') cannot be found. To build using the v143 build tools, please install v143 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution".

I have visual studio 2019 installed and my project has specific things that only works on 2019, so I can not update this to 2022.

Do you know how can I solve this

Comment: Is it necessary to target v143? Otherwise target v142 which should be included in VS2019

Comment: If you can use another version, go to **Project Properties -> General -> Platform Toolset** and select a version that is available.

Answer (score 0):

As @wohlstad said in comment,

> go to Project Properties -> General -> Platform Toolset and select a version that is available.